# Mysql query should return empty cell if not found

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say i have 10 users, 3 users has access to application, and other 7 dont. I want that all 10 users will be displayed, those who has access and those who dont. Result should look like this:

`id  name    email                   role
1   user1   user1@user1.com         Super Admin
2   user2   user2@user2.com         Super Admin
5   user5   user5@user5.com         Super Admin
....
10       user10   user10@user10.com         0`

I have query which works fine, but returning just first 3 users who has role. So i need to see those who dont have roles too.

```
    SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, appr.role 
    FROM users as u
    JOIN users_application_roles as appr ON u.id=appr.user_id AND (SELECT id from applications where key='testkey' and appr.application_id=id)
```

Comment: Show us your two tables.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, other guys solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you must use a LEFT JOIN instead, as the users without a role doesn't exist in your `users_application_roles`-table. Your query should be:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, appr.role 
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN users_application_roles as appr ON u.id=appr.user_id AND (SELECT id from applications where key='testkey' and appr.application_id=id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are looking for is an "outer join". Just using the "JOIN" clause implicitly calls the "inner join" clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think with a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of JOIN you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  u.name,
  u.email,
  appr.role 
FROM
  users AS u 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users_application_roles AS appr 
    ON u.id = appr.user_id 
    AND 
    (SELECT 
      id 
    FROM
      applications 
    WHERE KEY = 'testkey' 
      AND appr.application_id = id)
```